# Nested namespaces in rails error accessing model with same name as namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `manager` and a `customer` controller.
When i want to list all the customers for a specific manager, i used to do it through the manager `show` action (because it was specific to a manager). So `if` a customer_id was found a different return value would be generated. But that left we with (sometimes huge) if branches.

```
Class Api::V1::ManagerController < ApiBaseController
   def show 
     if params.key?[:customer_id]
         ....
     else
         ....
     end
     render ..., status: 200
   end
```

To improve my design i introduced additional name spaces for sub resources. So to list all the customers for one specific manager i have a customer controller under the manager name space. There all actions specific to a manager related to a customer resource are going.

```
 Class Api::V1::Manager::CustomerController < Api:ApiBaseController
  def show
      Manager.find(params[:id] ...
      ...
     render ..., status: 200
 end
```

The routes.rb entry looks now like this

```
get 'manager/:manager_id/customer' => 'manager/customer#show'
```

When testing the new setup i receive now this error

```
"error":"uninitialized constant Api::V1::Manager::CustomerController::Manager
```

When i replace the `Manager.find(..)` line with another resource it is working, why cann't i access the Manager Resource anymore? I think it has something to do with the name of the namespace, but even renaming the namespace did not help.

Comment: Where is `Manager` defined? In `app/models/manager.rb` or in a sub-folder? Also, could you provide is with the class declaration of `manager`?

Comment: Hey, yes it`s defined in 'app/model/manager.rb' . What do you mean with class declaration?

Comment: First line of the file usually `class Manager < ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
::Manager.find(params[:id])
```

Prefixing with `::` will access the root namespace.